# How to format $date_gmt in nginx.conf file for Last-Modified header

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx, nginx-config

I have added the Last-Modified header in the `nginx.conf` for the response of my Vue app. I build and run using docker.

Here is the line which I have added in the file:

```
add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
```

By default, It formats the date in `Friday, 22-Jan-2021 13:03:55 UTC` and this is not a valid format. Valid format is: `Fri, 22 Jan 2021 13:03:55 GMT`

so, How to format the Last-Modified header in `nginx.conf` file as valid format OR Do I need any other configuration file?